# List distinct values based on a condition

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, distinct, having

List Distinct Value in Alphabet Column where all Alphabets that has RID 101 only Shall be eliminated from the list.

| RID | Alphabet |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | A |
| 101 | B |
| 102 | B |
| 101 | C |
| 104 | D |
| 101 | D |
| 106 | E |
| 102 | F |
| 108 | C |
| 108 | A |
| 104 | E |

Output Column shall be

| Alphabet |
| --- |
| A |
| E |
| F |

Since A, B, & C has RID 101 and should be eliminated.

How shall I achieve This?
I have tried to use Group by with having function? And Where exists but did not work for me? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```sql
SELECT Alphabet FROM `mytable` WHERE Alphabet NOT IN (
  SELECT Alphabet FROM `mytable` WHERE RID = 101
)
```

Based on your new info your solution might be a performance killer because of using `HAVING MAX(when case...)`. But with `Rating.rID` as index the solution below will work very well:

```sql
Select Movie.title From Movie
  Left Join Rating on Rating.mID = Movie.mID
  Left Join Reviewer on Rating.rID = Reviewer.rID
  WHERE Movie.mID NOT IN (
    SELECT Rating.mID FROM Rating WHERE Rating.rID = 205
  )
GROUP BY Movie.mID
```

Comment: Did not work for me mate. Maybe because my actual structure of database is different. Let me share the full code that worked for me on actual so I learn alternative way as well.  
Select Movie.title
From  Movie
Left Join Rating on Rating.mID = Movie.mID
Left Join Reviewer on Rating.rID = Reviewer.rID
Group by Movie.mID having Max(case when Reviewer.rID = 205 then 1 else 0 end) =0;

Comment: @Saleem updated the answer, check it out! vote up and accept if it was helpful!

Comment: Thanks bro. using above it worked with me with small adjustment. I was still missing two movies from the list since not all movies have been rated by reviewers. so I changed **Where Rating.mID Not IN to Movie.mID Not IN**.

Comment: @Saleem you're right. accept an answer as your working answer by clicking the tick on the side of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

> How shall I achieve this? I have tried to use `group by` with `having`

Yes. You can just `GROUP BY` alphabet letter (which satisfies the *distinct* requirement), and exclude those that have the forbidden RID with a `HAVING` clause:

```
select alphabet
from mytable
group by alphabet
having max(case when rid = 101 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Depending on your database, there may be other ways to express the `HAVING` predicate; in Postgres, for example, which supports boolean aggregation:

```
having bool_and(rid != 101)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! It worked perfectly. I was close but since just started learning sql I was not able to figure out the right syntax of HAVING.